# Animation skipping when navigating to another page

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble finding the reason why a navigation animation is so laggy when launching an app for the first time. Here's the code of 3 files that should get you exactly what I have.

login.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navtest/main.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login Page'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage())),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

placeholder.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PlaceholderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlaceholderPageState createState() => _PlaceholderPageState();
}

class _PlaceholderPageState extends State<PlaceholderPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[Center(child: Text('Placeholder Page'))],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navtest/placeholder.dart';
import 'login.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Widget> pages = [PlaceholderPage(), PlaceholderPage()];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.remove),
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        initialIndex: 0,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: TabBarView(
            children: pages,
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
              ),
            ],
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            labelColor: Colors.orange,
            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Do you also experience a sluggish transition? Am I using a very demanding structure that I should switch for something else?

Comment: did you run your app in release mode ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it does the same in release mode.